# How do I install default raspbian programs on a raspberry pi already running emulation station?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, emulation

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a 32 GB SD card.  I put a pre-made image with an emulation station on. It launches the emulation station on boot and I installed the desktop so that I can use the Pi like a normal one running Raspbian when I want to.

My problem is that I don't have all of the programs that come default with a **Rapsbian** image. I really like the way I have the emulation station set up so I want to know how to install the programs without having to redo all the customisation and games on the Pi.

Comment: Which default programs are you missing?

Comment: One of the programs I know is missing is sonic pi. I haven't found a list of all the programs that come on raspbian images either, so that would be helpful too.

Comment: There's a whole shebang of software that comes with Raspbian. What do you want/need?

Answer (score 1):

To install any software, simply run the command:

`sudo apt-get update` (*this updates the list of repositories and which version of which software is available*)
followed by the command

`sudo apt-get install name_of_software_package`

In the case of Sonic Pi, the package name is `sonic-pi`.